# How can I read only new partition files that has been incrementally loaded to the datalake?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-data-lake

I wanted to check if you could help me think of an implementation for the following scenario?

Imagine I have a pipeline process from landing to bronze, there's nothing complex going on but the point is, I am incrementally reading data from a particular source in the landing zone, where I am getting new registers and partitioning them by date.

Once I get to the Bronze layer script I want to read these new partitions and create delta tables with it, but the point where I am struggling is how do I get just the new partition files that has been added to the lake since the last execution, the folders with the files are being saved in the landing zone in this format:

`DATE=2023-09-01 DATE=2023-09-10 DATE=2023-09-13 DATE=2023-09-23`

Let's say that just the last two partition folders has been added since last execution, so these are the ones I want to read only, I was thinking of a way to pass a window of partition folders to be read, but I have no clue where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated, by the way I am using Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

For streaming data you can use `Auto loader`,
you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/etl-quick-start) documentation for that.

If you don't want to use `Auto loader` you can follow below approach.

Below are partitions in landing zone.

[image]

Next, for initially if delta table does not exist then do a full load.
If the table is there then update the new partition data.

```
landing_zone = "/landing_zone_path/"
if spark.catalog.tableExists("bronze_tbl") is False:
    print("bronze_tbl not created.Doing full load")
    df = spark.read.format("delta").load(landing_zone)
    df.write.saveAsTable("bronze_tbl","delta")
else:
    print("Appending new partitions.")
    last_execution_time = DeltaTable.forName(spark,"bronze_tbl").history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
    df = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"/landing_zone_path/").toDF().select("*","_metadata.file_modification_time").filter(col("file_modification_time")>last_execution_time).drop("file_modification_time")
    df.writeTo("bronze_tbl").append()
```

Now let's add new partitions, below are the new partitions adding into landing zone.
4 records on date 28th and 29th.

[image]

Next, executing above code will add new data to table.

[image].